# Multi module projects with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have a project called `Frontend-Core-Components` which contains my App component.

I have another project (let's just call it `Alpha` for now) which contains`AlphaApiService`, which I pass to the App component via its props, I do this in Alpha's `index.tsx`

`Alpha` uses Create-react-app, I'm using rescript to modify the Webpack config to add Frontend-core-components as a module, Inside this Webpack configuration, I use `resolve.alias` to map imports from Alpha `index.tsx` to the `Frontend-Core-Components`.

It all seems to work, except when I run the build from Alpha project, I encounter the following.

```
  SyntaxError: /Users/coolguy/project/alpha/src/index.tsx: Unexpected token (9:11)

   7 |
   8 | window.onload = () => {
>  9 |     render(<App apiService={new AlphaApiService()} />, 
document.getElementById('root'))
         |                    ^
      10 | }
      11 |
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can [include](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleinclude) the `Frontend-Core-Components` in your `ts-loader`(or `babel-loader`) rule.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile your import module, before importing it.

I would suggest checking out this project to create React component  libraries.

https://github.com/KaiHotz/react-rollup-boilerplate